# What is Use Azurite for runtime storage account (AzureWebJobsStorage)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-functions-runtime

I have just started creating azure functions. I am creating a new azure function and got the below option. what does it mean? what if I select or unselect it? I have not found any documentation about it.

[image]

It shows this info, but I didn't understand it at all.

[image]

Comment: Azurite is local storage emulator

Comment: what does that mean? What if I select/unselect it? Can you explain?

Comment: When you create a function you need to storage account for it. In Portal you will be created a function with storage account, when work locally you need this(it contains storage apis)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create an Azure Function, there needs to be an Azure Storage Account behind it, for various runtime needs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage).

For local development, you can choose to either use a real Azure Storage Account in the cloud by setting AzureWebJobsStorage app setting to that storage account's connection string, or you can use a local emulator (Azurite) that simulates a Storage Account on your machine.

So if you select that Azurite box, it will set AzureWebJobsStorage to use your local emulator instead, therefore no need for a storage account in the cloud.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio